# Does Keycloak expose WebAuthn APIs or can Webauthn flow be managed programmatically

Tags: spring-boot, keycloak, webauthn, fido, password-less

We are currently evaluating Keycloak Passwordless login feature which is called Webauthn and follows FIDO2 specification.
I am able to customize authentication flow (through admin console of keycloak) and login with fido2 device (platform authenticator of my Mac), it works fine.

[image]

[image]

However I cannot find an option to register user through Webauthn flow. Below are the questions:

1. Is it something currently supported in keycloak ?
2. Can Webauthn flow be managed programmatically? Using keycloak spring boot starter and etc.

Thanks